# C# polymorphism in Generic types

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

```
class Base
{}

class Sub : Base
{}


void AddNewBase(Base t, LinkedList<Base> list){ ... }
...
{

    Sub asub = new Sub();

    LinkedList<Sub> asubList = new LinkedList<Sub>();
    AddNewBase(asub,asubList) // doesn't work
}
```

basically, I have a custom insert function that takes a new item and a list to put it in, and it does some 'sorting' stuff to find a good place to put it in the list.

problem is, I want to do this based on properties in 'Base'  so it would be good to have just one function that could do this for all lists of sub types.

I think what I kind of want is:

```
static void AddNewBase<T>(T t, LinkedList<T> list){ ... }
```

but with some way of clarifying T like: 'where T is a sub class of Base'

Comment: There are no templates in C#.

Comment: which version ? C# 4 and .NET 4 have ways of doing this. Previous versions have not.

Comment: In this case .NET 4.0 doesn't help much, because `LinkedList<T>` is neither covariant nor contravariant. Generally, you need the generic type to be either "read-only" (e.g. `IEnumerable<T>`) or "write-only" (e.g. `Action<T>`) to allow covariance or contravariance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can declare [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
static void AddNewBase<T>(T t, LinkedList<T> list) where T : Base { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **where** keyword in the same way and you do not need a generic type.

Here is the `IComparable` implementation which probably is what you could be looking for in a classic sorting problem:

```
    static void AddNewBase<T>(T t, LinkedList<T> list) where T : IComparable
    {
        //
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# 4, you can use covariance to make this work. You have to select from one of the covariant generic collection interfaces though. For example, redeclaring your method as:

```
static void AddNewBase(Base t, IEnumerable<Base> list) { //... }
```

Would allow you to call `AddNewBase` with a `LinkedList<Sub>`.